# Tautly embedding a ball quotient

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{B}^n$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $\Gamma$ be a fixed-point free, discrete subgroup of the automorphism group of $\mathbb{B}^n$. Let $M := \mathbb{B}^n / \Gamma$. Then $M$ is a complete Kobayashi hyperbolic manifold. Consequently $M$ is a taut manifold, i.e, every sequence of holomorphic mappings $\{f_n: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{B}^n\}$ has either a compactly convergent subsequence or a compactly divergent subsequence.

I want to know under what conditions on $\Gamma$ I can embed $M$ into another complex manifold $N$ such that every sequence $f_n: \mathbb{D} \to M$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on compacts to a holomorphic map 
$f: \mathbb{D} \to \overline{M}$, where I view $M$ as a subset of $N$ and take the closure in $N$. In this situation, we say that $M$ is tautly embedded in $N$. For further details see [Abate's book](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~abate/libri/libriric/files/IterationThTautMan2-1.pdf)

In dimension $1$, it is easy to see that this happens when $M$ is a hyperbolic punctured Riemann surface. In this case $\Gamma$ will be a Fuchsian group of divergence type. The notion of divergence type has been generalized to higher dimension, see [section 2 of the paper by Shiga](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1190905450). Is it true that the quotient of the unit ball with a subgroup of the automorphism group of divergence type can be tautly embedded in some complex manifold?